# JMenu-JMenuItem doesn't appear

Tags: java, swing, awt, jmenu, jmenuitem

My problem with this code is that when I run it the `JMenuItem` doesn't appear. I'm so confused! Anyone can help?

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
public class NewClass extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
JFrame window = new JFrame("Ηλεκτρονικό Έντυπο Υπερωριών");
JMenu menu = new JMenu("Example");
JMenuItem menuItem = new JMenuItem("hi");
public NewClass(){
    window.setSize(200,200);
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    menu.add(menuItem);
    menuItem.addActionListener(this);

    window.add(menu);
    window.pack();
    window.setVisible(true);
        }
public static void main(String []args){
    NewClass example = new NewClass();
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add a menubar to the window. To this menubar you add your menu(s). Take a look at oracle's tutorial on [How to Use Menus](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html).

Comment: i cant just have a single menu with items in it without menu bar? Imagine something like 'you ask a question and you have a menu with multiple answers for the user to choose' How can i accomplish this?

Comment: What is against using a menubar? Could you provide an example how it should look like? I think a `JMenu` isn't the right component you are looking for

Comment: What you are looking for is the `JComboBox`. 
Here you see how to use it https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html